# Sequentially sum values restarting sum total on every change

Tags: sql-server

I have these values in a column:
     1
     1
     1
     -1
     -1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     -1
     1

I need a query that will return the first sequential sum of values and then the next one and so forth, every time the value differs from the one before a new sum will be performed.
The result of these sequential sums, according to the example, will be the following:

```
 3
 -2
 5
 -1
 1
```

What will be the best approach to do this in terms of speed and resource usage, a loop through each value and calculate each sum or can this be done in one query?
Any ideas please?

----------   EDITION   ------------

I managed to add the following column using the row_number over partition by:

```
COL A   COL B
1       1
2       1
3       1
1      -1
2      -1
1       1
2       1
3       1
```

.... and so forth

Can this help in any way?

--------- Second Edition ---------
I have this:

```
  SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.RES ORDER BY T.ID_Test_Case DESC) AS GRP,
          T.RES,
          T.ID_Test_Case
  FROM    (
            SELECT TEST_CASE.ID_Test_Case,
                   (CASE WHEN TEST_RESULT.Name = TR2.Name THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) AS RES
            FROM   (Join from all tables needed)
            WHERE (All Conditions) ) T
            ORDER BY T.ID_Test_Case DESC
          )
```

This is where I'm retrieving the values 1 and -1, which will always be ordered the same because of the order by clause. I can only use the Test_Case.ID to order and is a unique field... Hope this helps

Comment: the table contains other columns?

Comment: No. And just 1 or -1 as cell values.

Comment: Your request requires an ordering column.  You need another column in the table in order to support "sequential sums."  Relational DB tables are by default unordered.

Comment: But I don't need to reorder the values, I need the values just like they are.
Or what kind of ordering are you referring to?

Comment: Can I use any recursive approach?

Comment: The ordering comment is because a table is an unordered set. You are indicating you expect the concept "next" and "previous". From the data you posted there is no way to know what the order is. You should be able to do this fairly easily using SUM with a case expression and a partition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sean, can you post an example?

Comment: @KevinSuchlicki makes great points about the ordering column. My answer just solves your question, but you may need to ensure your approach is correct.

Comment: This would work a lot better if you had a different column for when the value changed. Then is would just be a windowing function with the PARTITION BY clause.

Comment: Also, to expand on what @SeanLange was saying: Sql Server does not guarantee the order of the results! This time you get `1 1 1 -1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 -1 1`. Next time you run the same query, you might get `1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1`. The time after, you might get something else entirely. Without an ORDER BY clause, Sql Server will show the results in whatever way it thinks will be most efficient. If the order of the rows matters, you **must** have some column you can use to specify an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: @maufonfa Your edit still is insufficient.  Does the 5th value (ordered as "2") follow the 4th value (ordered as "1") or the 1st value (also ordered as "1")?  I know it's obvious to us, but not to the DB engine.  There needs to be one and only one way to order the data.  Add a column ordered sequentially from 1 to 12 and the solution is not difficult with a single query.

Comment: Kevin you meant an identity column? once I have added that how can I do a single query... can you show me?

Comment: I know the order will always be the same because this column is a result of a query pre-ordered by id and the 1 is occurring on the true part of the case and the -1 in the else.<br/>
I can have an identity column from 1 to n... now if I had this how can it be done in one sigle query @KevinSuchlicki ???

Comment: @SeanLange.. this info is enough???

Comment: What do you mean by pre-ordered? The ONLY way to ensure the order of results is by using ORDER BY.

Comment: I see you added some new values with RowNumber. I assume ColA is the "ordering" column? That isn't going to work. We need to know how to order the entire set. If we put an order by on the list it will NOT be returned in the order you posted which is what I suspect you want. This really isn't that difficult but you not providing details makes it impossible to help.

Comment: @SeanLange Watch the new edition to see tif this info helps in any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a recursive CTE:

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE
(
    RowID   int IDENTITY(1,1),
    Value   int
)

INSERT INTO @tmp
    VALUES (1),(1),(1),(-1),(-1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(-1),(1)

;WITH
    Groups AS
    (
        SELECT      RowID       As GroupID,
                    RowID       As RowID,
                    Value       As Value
        FROM        @tmp
        WHERE       RowID = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT      CASE
                        WHEN this.Value = prev.Value THEN prev.GroupID
                        ELSE this.RowID
                    END         As GroupID,
                    this.RowID  As RowId,
                    this.Value  AS Value
        FROM        @tmp    this
        INNER JOIN  Groups  prev    ON this.RowID = prev.RowID + 1
    )

SELECT      SUM(Value)
FROM        Groups
GROUP BY    GroupID
```

**Explanation:**

1. What you want is to segregate rows into groups of sequentially equal values. The `RowID` here is used as the row number.
2. The CTE starts with `RowID = 1`, creating a new "group"
3. The `UNION ALL` recursively adds in `RowID = 2, 3, 4` etc. With each iteration, it considers if its value is equal to the previous row's value. If it is, it uses the same `GroupID` as the previous row. If not, a new group is started with its `RowID`.
4. We now simply need to sum up the value in each group to get what you want.

To see how the internals of this work, replace the final `SELECT` with `SELECT * FROM Groups`

Answer (score 2):

Should be self-explanatory. Not elegant, but will get the job done.

```
Create Table _Numbercolumn (val int)
Create Table _RandValues ( random int)
Create Table _Sum([sum] int)

insert into _RandValues values(1)
insert into _RandValues values(-1)
while ( select COUNT(val) from _Numbercolumn ) < 100
BEGIN 
    Insert into _numbercolumn select top 1 random from _RandValues order by NEWID()
END


DECLARE Number_Cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT val from _Numbercolumn
DECLARE @CurrentSum int, @CursorVal int
OPEN Number_Cursor;
Set @CurrentSum = 0 

FETCH NEXT FROM Number_Cursor into @CursorVal;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
    IF SIGN(@CurrentSum) <> SIGN(@CursorVal)
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO _Sum Values(@CurrentSum)
        SET @CurrentSum = @CursorVal    
        END
    ELSE
        SET @CurrentSum = @CurrentSum + @CursorVal
    FETCH NEXT FROM Number_Cursor into @CursorVal;
    END;
CLOSE Number_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE Number_Cursor;
GO

Select * from _Sum
```

Comment: I know this could get the job done but I need an efficient way to do it, cause it will be done on a lot of rows.

Comment: I don't think this can be done in one query. My method uses a cursor, which is most likely not the best approach, but runs in O(n) time where n is the number of records. So if you can improve the cursor implementation it should work for your purposes.

Comment: This can be done without a cursor but we need to know what column we can use as an order.

Comment: Sean can I create a column to use it for ordering purposes? I added this row_number sequentially...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the same set as yours with unique ordering:

```
SELECT  *
INTO    #t
FROM    (VALUES (1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,-1),(5,-1),(6,1),(7,1),(8,1),(9,1),(10,1),(11,-1),(12,1)) AS t(RowNbr, VALUE);
```

Now, using the above, you can do it in a single query (there is probably an even better way of doing it, but this should suffice):

```
;WITH ChangingRows AS (
    SELECT  t1.RowNbr, t1.Value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.RowNbr) AS Ord
    FROM    #t t1
            LEFT JOIN #t t2 ON t1.RowNbr = t2.RowNbr - 1 
    WHERE   t1.Value != ISNULL(t2.Value, 0)
)
SELECT  (c1.RowNbr - ISNULL(c2.RowNbr, 0)) * c1.Value as Total
FROM    ChangingRows c1
        LEFT JOIN ChangingRows c2 ON c2.Ord = c1.Ord - 1;
```