# SQL: How to "aggregate sequences"?

Tags: sql, teradata

My question is a little bit hard to explain.
I've got a table that looks like this

```
column1 | column2 | date
------------------------------------------                                      
  u01     test       2001-01-01
  u01     test       2001-02-01
  u01     test2      2001-03-01
  u01     test2      2001-04-01
  u01     test3      2001-05-01
  u01     test       2001-06-01
```

In my destination table, I want to aggregate same values but only if they "follow" each other. That means my destination table would look like this:

```
   column1 | column2 | validfrom        validto
    ------------------------------------------                                      
      u01     test       2001-01-01     2001-03-01
      u01     test2      2001-03-01     2001-05-01   
      u01     test3      2001-05-01     2001-06-01
      u01     test       2001-06-01
```

I tried working with rownumber, so that at the moment I am getting some numbered lines, but there stills remains the problem, that I don't know how to "aggregate sequences".

[image]

Any ideas or approaches are appreciated!

Comment: Looks similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185007/sequentially-sum-values-restarting-sum-total-on-every-change
So using a recursive CTE will be best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a nice extension in Teradata to normalize periods:

```
SELECT
   column1
  ,column2
  -- split the Period into seperate columns again
  ,Begin(pd)
  ,NullIf(End(pd), DATE '9999-12-31')
FROM
 (
   SELECT NORMALIZE -- normalize overlapping periods
      column1
     ,column2
      -- NORMALIZE only works with periods, so create a Period based on current & next row
     ,PERIOD(date
            ,Coalesce(Lead(date) 
                      Over (PARTITION BY column1 
                            ORDER BY date)
                     ,DATE '9999-12-31')
            ) AS pd
   FROM tab
 ) AS dt
```

If your Teradata release doesn't support `LEAD`, yet, you can use this instead:

```
Min(date) 
Over  (PARTITION BY column1 
       ORDER BY date
       ROWS BETWEEN 1 Following and 1 Following)
```

Comment: Wow. This seems to be really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  Here is a solution using row numbers:

```
select column1, column2, min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by column1 order by date) as seqnum_1,
             row_number() over (partition by column1, column2 order by date) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by column1, column2, (seqnum_1 - seqnum_2);
```

Why this works is a little tricky to explain.  I find that it is pretty obvious if you look at the results of the subquery.  You'll see how the difference in the row numbers defines the groups that you are trying to find.

Comment: " (partition by column1, column_2 order by date) "  did you mean column2

Comment: anyways resolving syntax error still output is wrong

Comment: @kirangadhe . . . What syntax error?  The query looks like what I intend.

Comment: look in second partition by column_2 should be column2 (it must be typo i guss)

Comment: @GordonLinoff. . . I don't think this would produce desired result.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in your case

```
        set @rnum = 0   
        set @col1 = ''    
        set @col2 = ''    
        SELECT YY.col1 AS col1, YY.col2 AS col2, rr.aamin AS valid_from, rr.bbmin AS valid_to
        FROM (
            (
                SELECT col1, col2, num
                FROM (
                    SELECT CASE 
                            WHEN @col1 = @col1
                                THEN @rnum
                            ELSE @rnum + 1
                            END AS num, @col1 = column1 AS column1, @col2 = column2 AS column1, DATE_1
                    FROM test t
                    )
                GROUP BY col1, col2, num
                ) YY INNER JOIN (
                SELECT *
                FROM (
                    SELECT num AS aanum, min(AA.DATE_1) AS aamin
                    FROM (
                        SELECT CASE 
                                WHEN @col1 = @col1
                                    THEN @rnum
                                ELSE @rnum + 1
                                END AS num, @col1 = column1 AS column1, @col2 = column2 AS column1, DATE_1
                        FROM test t
                        ) AA
                    ) GG
                LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT num AS bbnum, min(DATE_1) AS bbmin(SELECT CASE 
                                WHEN @col1 = @col1
                                    THEN @rnum
                                ELSE @rnum + 1
                                END AS num, @col1 = column1 AS column1, @col2 = column2 AS column1, DATE_1 FROM test t)
                    GROUP BY num
                    ) BB
                    ON (GG.aanum + 1 = BB.bbnum)
                )
            ) RR
            ON RR.aanum = yy.num
```